# Append subchildnode

Tags: c#, xml, appendchild

I'm stuck with some task here. I want to write to xml file.

Here is the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<lists>
<plannedList>
    <Skift-a></Skift-a>
    <Skift-b></Skift-b>
    <Skift-c></Skift-c>
    <Skift-d></Skift-d>
    <Skift-e></Skift-e>
  </plannedList>
  <requestedList>
    <Skift-a></Skift-a>
    <Skift-b></Skift-b>
    <Skift-c></Skift-c>
    <Skift-d></Skift-d>
    <Skift-e></Skift-e>
 </requestedList>
</lists>
```

then i want to use c# and for example dataset or an other method to add a jobID under the loggedIn Skift. so if Skift-a is logged on, and press a button, i want the xml file to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<lists>
<plannedList>
    <Skift-a></Skift-a>
    <Skift-b></Skift-b>
    <Skift-c></Skift-c>
    <Skift-d></Skift-d>
    <Skift-e></Skift-e>
  </plannedList>
  <requestedList>
    <Skift-a></Skift-a>
        <jobID>1<jobID/>
    <Skift-b></Skift-b>
    <Skift-c></Skift-c>
    <Skift-d></Skift-d>
    <Skift-e></Skift-e>
 </requestedList>
</lists>
```

And here is what I've tried so far:

```
        XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmldoc.Load(this.Page.Server.MapPath("~/StoredData/JobsByUsers.xml"));

        XmlNode Skift = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("/requestedList/" + User.Identity.Name.ToString());

        XmlNode newJobID = xmldoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "jobID", null);
        newJobID.InnerText = topID.ToString();


        Skift.AppendChild(newJobID);

        xmldoc.Save(this.Page.Server.MapPath("~/StoredData/JobsByUsers.xml"));
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://bit.ly/THx3lZ)?

Comment: Off courese i've googled it, but everywhere they are explaining how to append under root. Like if i want a new list with all the skifts.